# Has many through association not working in upgrade rails 3 to rails 4 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Question I have this has many through in my model for some reason I keep getting this error and help would be greatly appreciated.

## Error

`ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError (Could not find the association #<Proc:0x0055e57679b2b8@/home/dev/testapp/app/models/work_order.rb:12> in model WorkOrder)`:

```
 has_many :demand_supply_links,
            :through => proc {"select * from demand_supply_link
                                     where supply_type = 'WO'" +
                                    " and supply_base_id = '" + "#{base_id}" +
                                    "' and supply_lot_id = '" + "#{lot_id}" +
                                    "' and supply_split_id = '" + "#{split_id}" + "'"}
```

where I use the trough association

```
def setup(session)
  if !@work_order.nil?
    @demand_supply = @work_order.demand_supply_links.first
  end 
end
```

Comment: Post your code containing model associations

Comment: I edited my question @Bijendra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just define a method for it rather than a `has_many :through`? 
e.g

```
def demand_supply_links
    DemandSupplyLink.where(supply_type: 'WO',
                           supply_base_id: base_id,
                           supply_lot_id: lot_id,
                           supply_split_id: split_id)
end
```

This will perform the same operations you are requesting and does not involve raw SQL. It will also handle sanitation much better than string concatenation.

Comment: Haha thanks I just thought about it and actually did that before I could check back on my question.  @engineersmnky